# Installation of mono-fastcgi-server4 file not found

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, fastcgi-mono-server

I have searched the web and stackoverflow for how to install mono-fastcgi-server4.  It is supposed to be part of a mono distribution or xsp.  I have installed mono, monodevelop, xsp, mono-mvc-develop and searched my drive from the top level, but can not find mono-fastcgi-server* anywhere.  All of the tutorials and examples have this installed with the other components.  What package am I missing?  I'm on Centos 6.4.

Comment: This post was interesting: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=31227  It appears for some reason the xsp package on centos does not include this executable.  I have not had luck with building from source for xsp, so if anyone can point to a repo with this for centos that would be great.

Comment: This is the packager's fault, as mono-fastcgi-server{2,4} is part of xsp.

What error did you get when building from source? What version of mono are you using?

Comment: I am using mono 2.10.5.  I wish I could tell you when / how I got fastcgi-mono-server4 installed, but I tried to build / install so many related packages that I'm just not sure.  But the good news is that I have fastcgi-mono-server4 running and it appears to be working. So I'm not so concerned with the source version working right now.  But now I have another package problem.  I can build / run my ASP.NET web app from monodevelop / xsp, but not an nginx -> mono-fastcgi request because it is missing System.Web.Extensions.

Comment: I am going to attempt a cheat and find a 4.0 version of System.Web.Extensions.dll and put it in the /usr/lib64/mono/4.0 directory.  I guess at this point any further follow-up on this part should be in a new question as it has deviated from the original topic.  But thanks for your input.